# 2 column grid, multiple rows in one. How do I make them equal in height?

Tags: height, equals, zurb-foundation, multiple-columns

I'd like to put 3 images next to one image in a responsive row layout but I can't figure out how to make the contents of this row to be equal in height. I can make the images any dimension if it's as simple as "The large image should be 900x1200px, the 3 small ones should be 300x500px"  I am also using foundation4 for this as well. The images could be cropped or stretched a little too.

http://jsfiddle.net/uEyCF/2/

```
<div id="image_box">

  <div class="col">
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/200x350" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
<div id="image_box" class="row">
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns left-col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x340" />
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.left-col img { margin-bottom:20px; float:right;}
</style>
```

Comment: That's very similar to what I have now. The problem, as you'll see in my fiddle, is that the bottom of the 3rd image in the left column and the bottom of the larger image do not line up. As I said, I can make these images any size that I want but what I am trying to solve is with a responsive layout, the height of these images change based on the width so I would like the bottoms of these images to line up regardless of the window size. Could I stretch or crop these 3 smaller images based on the height of the single larger image?